# Updating custom properties when exporting data from DXL DOORS to Word using template containing VBA macros

Tags: vba, ms-word, ibm-doors

I am writing a DXL script that would export data from IBM Rational DOORS to MS Word. I am using a template (.docm) using which the export happens and I have written macros in the template which will be used by DXL during execution.

I am facing a problem when updating the Document properties (Custom). I am using the below code, but the document properties are not being updated.

Sub macro_name(text As String)

Dim sPropName As String

sPropName = "Autor"

ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties(sPropName).Value = text

End Sub

Could anyone please advice.

Comment: Is the property name "Autor" or "Author"? There is a BuiltinDocumentProperty named Author and if that's the one you want then you need to correct both the spelling and the property name you're using.
If the property is, indeed, Autor then you need to make sure it's pre-defined in the template, under the Custom Properties tab in the Word UI's Document Properties dialog box.

Comment: Note that the actual property name "Author" is used even if the UI of your environment displays a different name as the translation of the English "Author". A BuiltinDocumentProperty is one that displays on any tab other than the Custom Properties tab.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in the Word Object model. Read the section for the "Remarks"
here [Document.CustomDocumentProperties Property (Word)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ff195603.aspx)

Use this code.

```
Sub macro_name(text As String)

    Dim sPropName As String

    sPropName = "Autor"
    ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties(sPropName).Value = text

End Sub
```

Hope this helps :)